# Associate data in a table from several crossed tables

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012.

We have Orders from several companies. Each Order can have one or more  Sales Order Line.
And the Order Line can have one Article, but it never has more than one Article. However, the same article can appear in several Sales Order Line.

Table **Order** - FinalCustomerId is a foreign key for Customer

```
Id   FinalCustomerId  Code
1    2                 X45
2    1                 O30
3    2                 Y74
4    5                 XY0
```

Table **Customer**

```
Id   Name
1    XPTO
2    BOSS
3    TREND
4    XIPS
5    VALLEY
```

Table **Article**

```
Id   Name
1    DVD
2    San Disk
3    CD
4    SPAM
```

Table **OrderLine** (ordered by OrderId and then by Number) - OrderId is a foreign key for Order, and ArticleId if FK for Article.

```
Id   Number   OrderId   ArticleId   
1    10       1             1
3    20       1             1
4    30       1             1
7    40       1             2

6    10       2             2
8    20       2             1

2    10       3             2 
5    20       3             2
9    10       4             4
```

Note: This table has 3 Orders, and only the third order has one type of article (id 2).

Table **CustomerArticleMark** - MainArticleId is a FK for Article

```
Id   FinalCustomerId      MainArticleId   
1           2                    1
2           2                    2
3           1                    3
4           5                    2
5           3                    2
6           5                    4
```

**Aim**: For each line of CustomerArticleMark associate the respective Sales Order code that have the article.

Rules:

1. article in CustomerArticleMark  appears in 5 Order Lines in two Orders, so Main Article must appear 2 times and not 5 times;
2. article in CustomerArticleMark  appears in 5 Order Lines in one Order, so Main Article must appear only ONCE and not 5 times;
3. article in CustomerArticleMark  does not appear in any Order Lines , so Main Article should appear but with an empty value for Sales Order code;
4. article in CustomerArticleMark must be unique for each distinct article in Sales Order Line per Order and per FinalCustomer in Order. There are Orders with the same article but different final customer.

Starting in the last table, the desired result should be this one:

**Final Table  - desired result.**

```
Id (of CustomerArticleMark)   FinalCustomer      MainArticle     SALES ORDER Code 
 
    1                               BOSS              DVD                 X45
   
    2                               BOSS              SanDisk             Y74
    3                               XPTO              CD      (there is no o. line with article 3)      
    4                               VALLEY            SanDisk  -
    5                               TREND             SanDisk       (no final customer id5 in Order)
    6                               VALLEY            SPAM                XY0
```

It should appear all these six rows. Only in lines with id 3, 4 and 5 the sales order code must be empty, but the rest must be filled!

I have tried with T-SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  
                   {CustomerArticleMark}.[Id]
                ,  {Customer}.[Name] AS FinalCustomer
                ,  {Article}.[Name] AS MainArticle
                ,  {Order}.[Code] AS SALES ORDER Code
                
             
                FROM {CustomerArticleMark} 
                LEFT JOIN {Customer} ON {Customer}.[Id] = {CustomerArticleMark}.[FinalCustomerId] 
                LEFT JOIN {Article} ON {Article}.[Id] = {CustomerArticleMark}.[MainArticleId] 
                LEFT JOIN {SalesOrderLine} ON {SalesOrderLine}.[ArticleId] = {Article}.[Id]
                LEFT JOIN {Order} ON {Order}.[Id] = {SalesOrderLine}.[OrderId]
                WHERE {Order}.[FinalCustomerId] = {CustomerArticleMark}.[FinalCustomerId]
```

I get this:

```
Id (of CustomerArticleMark)   FinalCustomer      MainArticle     SALES ORDER Code 
 
    1                               BOSS              DVD                 X45
    1                               BOSS              SanDisk*            X45*
    
    2                               BOSS              SanDisk             Y74
    6                               VALLEY            SPAM                XY0
```

it is not appearing the 3, 4 and 5 but it should appear with sales order code empty.

The difference is marked with an asterisk. How can we get the desired result?
Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, since SalesOrderLine is directly linked to Order we should INNER JOIN them to treat as a single entity. And then we can join this to the CustomerArticleMark. Please try below ...

```
SELECT DISTINCT  
                   {CustomerArticleMark}.[Id]
                ,  {Customer}.[Name] AS FinalCustomer
                ,  {Article}.[Name] AS MainArticle
                ,  {Order}.[Code] AS SALES ORDER Code
                
             
                FROM {CustomerArticleMark} 
                LEFT JOIN ( {SalesOrderLine} INNER JOIN {Order} ON {Order}.[Id] = {SalesOrderLine}.[OrderId]) ON {SalesOrderLine}.[ArticleId] = {CustomerArticleMark}.[MainArticleId]
                AND {Order}.[FinalCustomerId] = {CustomerArticleMark}.[FinalCustomerId]
                LEFT JOIN {Customer} ON {Customer}.[Id] = {CustomerArticleMark}.[FinalCustomerId] 
                LEFT JOIN {Article} ON {Article}.[Id] = {CustomerArticleMark}.[MainArticleId]
```

Also, in your desired results I don't think you can have the below as the MainArticleId/FinalCustomerId do not have a matching Orderline/Order -

```
Id (of CustomerArticleMark)   FinalCustomer      MainArticle     SALES ORDER Code 

1                               BOSS              DVD                 Y74 
6                               VALLEY            SPAM                XY0
```

Or, if you wanted to use a CTE ( I've also used GROUP BY below, you could used DISTICNT)

```
;WITH cte as (
SELECT [SalesOrderLine].[ArticleId] , [Order].[FinalCustomerId] , [Order].[Code]  FROM [SalesOrderLine] INNER JOIN [Order] ON [Order].[Id] = [SalesOrderLine].[OrderId])
SELECT 
                   [CustomerArticleMark].[Id]
                ,  [Customer].[Name] AS FinalCustomer
                ,  [Article].[Name] AS MainArticle
                ,  [cte].[Code] AS [SALES ORDER Code]
                
                FROM [CustomerArticleMark] 
                LEFT JOIN [cte] ON [cte].[ArticleId] = [CustomerArticleMark].[MainArticleId]
                AND [cte].[FinalCustomerId] = [CustomerArticleMark].[FinalCustomerId]
                JOIN [Customer] ON [Customer].[Id] = [CustomerArticleMark].[FinalCustomerId] 
                JOIN [Article] ON [Article].[Id] = [CustomerArticleMark].[MainArticleId] 
GROUP BY             [CustomerArticleMark].[Id]
                ,  [Customer].[Name] 
                ,  [Article].[Name] 
                ,  [cte].[Code]
```

Comment: It does not do the trick yet. But thanks.

Comment: yes, I forgot to put in Sales Order line the record id 9. For the Id 1 of customer article mark, you are right. Fixed.

Comment: ids 3, 4, 5 of CustomerArticleMark must have the columns of mainarticle and finalcostumer filled. They are empty..  correct is the sales order which is empty. It is better, though. But not exactly what it is intended.

Comment: @graphene. Customer and Article tables are directly outer joined to CustomerArticleMark, so it is not possible for them to be blank. I just tried it and it works. Do you want to post the exact query you are trying ?

Comment: You are right. I was using identifiers in the SELECT CLAUSE. Now it is exactly the desired! Thanks. :)

Comment: so the trick is to treat the order and order sales line like on single entity. Would it be possible to use CTE in this case? Would it be better? Thanks!

Comment: yes, CTE would work. It might be more readable, but performance wise I do not think it'll give any better result. What you could also try is to use GROUP BY instead of DISTINCT.

Comment: I always thought that using DISTINCT has a lower cost than using GROUP BY...  If possible could you provide a CTE example in this case? Thanks!

Comment: I've updated the answer with CTE. Let me know if that helps. Thanks